How to show abbreviations of State/Province instead of Full names in Magento 2
In Magento 2 customer account create I want to show abbreviations of State/Province instead of Full names.
So far I have changed this code but it is not working.
/vendor/magento/module-directory/Model/ResourceModel/Region/Collection.php

Inside function public function toOptionArray() chnaged $option['label'] = $item->getName(); to $option['label'] = $item->getCode();
Also changed
$propertyMap = [
            'value' => 'region_id',
            'title' => 'default_name',
            'country_id' => 'country_id',
        ];

to
$propertyMap = [
            'value' => 'region_id',
            'title' => 'code',
            'country_id' => 'country_id',
        ];



means you want the frontend side customer account page to add a state field.?

state/province is part of address form but I have added it in customer account create form and now want to show abbreviations, not the full names

Share your frontend display code what you are try.

@ishaq I will share my code in detail. so please check it. and accept my answer and upvote me.

I am overriding code as per requirement that is working so please check the below change.
first created a new module so please check all below step.
Created a new file registration.php /var/www/html/project/app/code/Test/Customregion/registration.php
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
'Test_Customregion',
__DIR__

);
another created new file module.xml file.
/var/www/html/project/app/code/Test/Customregion/etc/module.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
<module name="Test_Customregion" setup_version="1.0.0" >
</module>    
</config>

/var/www/html/project/app/code/Test/Customregion/etc/di.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Directory\Helper\Data" type="Test\Customregion\Helper\CustomData" />
</config>

created a new file Test\Customregion\Helper\CustomData.php add below code.
<?php

namespace Test\Customregion\Helper;
use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;
use Magento\Directory\Model\AllowedCountries;



class CustomData extends \Magento\Directory\Helper\Data
{    

private const STORE_ID = 'store_id';
/**
 * Retrieve current Product object
 *
 * @return \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product|null
 */
public function getRegionData()
{
    $scope = $this->getCurrentScope();
    $allowedCountries = $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
        AllowedCountries::ALLOWED_COUNTRIES_PATH,
        $scope['type'],
        $scope['value']
    ) ?? '';
    $countryIds = explode(',', $allowedCountries);
    $collection = $this->_regCollectionFactory->create();
    $collection->addCountryFilter($countryIds)->load();
    $regions = [
        'config' => [
            'show_all_regions' => $this->isShowNonRequiredState(),
            'regions_required' => $this->getCountriesWithStatesRequired(),
        ],
    ];
    foreach ($collection as $region) {
        /** @var $region \Magento\Directory\Model\Region */
        if (!$region->getRegionId()) {
            continue;
        }
        $regions[$region->getCountryId()][$region->getRegionId()] = [
            'code' => $region->getCode(),
            'name' => (string)__($region->getCode()),
        ];
    }
    return $regions;
}

private function getCurrentScope(): array
{
    $scope = [
        'type' => ScopeConfigInterface::SCOPE_TYPE_DEFAULT,
        'value' => null,
    ];
    $request = $this->_getRequest();
    if ($request->getParam(ScopeInterface::SCOPE_WEBSITE)) {
        $scope = [
            'type' => ScopeInterface::SCOPE_WEBSITE,
            'value' => $request->getParam(ScopeInterface::SCOPE_WEBSITE),
        ];
    } elseif ($request->getParam(ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE)) {
        $scope = [
            'type' => ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
            'value' => $request->getParam(ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE),
        ];
    } elseif ($request->getParam(self::STORE_ID)) {
        $scope = [
            'type' => ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
            'value' => $request->getParam(self::STORE_ID),
        ];
    } else {
        $storeId = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId() ?? null;
        if ($storeId) {
            $scope = [
                'type' => ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                'value' => $storeId,
            ];
        }
    }

    return $scope;
}

}
?>

after applying the below commands.
sudo php bin/magento s:up && sudo php bin/magento setup:di:compile && sudo php bin/magento s:static-content:de -f && sudo php bin/magento c:f && sudo chmod -R 777 var/ pub/ generated

I hope that is work. I will also share a screenshot. so please check it.
please accept my answer and upvote me.




hello dear I found a solution you want but if you override the below file then works. so please check it.
/var/www/html/project/vendor/magento/module-directory/Helper/Data.php
function name is
    public function getRegionData()
{
    $scope = $this->getCurrentScope();
    $allowedCountries = $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
        AllowedCountries::ALLOWED_COUNTRIES_PATH,
        $scope['type'],
        $scope['value']
    ) ?? '';
    $countryIds = explode(',', $allowedCountries);
    $collection = $this->_regCollectionFactory->create();
    $collection->addCountryFilter($countryIds)->load();
    $regions = [
        'config' => [
            'show_all_regions' => $this->isShowNonRequiredState(),
            'regions_required' => $this->getCountriesWithStatesRequired(),
        ],
    ];
    foreach ($collection as $region) {
        /** @var $region \Magento\Directory\Model\Region */
        if (!$region->getRegionId()) {
            continue;
        }
        $regions[$region->getCountryId()][$region->getRegionId()] = [
            'code' => $region->getCode(),
            'name' => (string)__($region->getCode()),
        ];
    }
    return $regions;
}

change only one line show please check it.
 'name' => (string)__($region->getName()), 

  to 

 'name' => (string)__($region->getCode()),

I will share the screenshot below. please don't forget to override the above file.

I hope that you get a solution please accept my answer and upvote me.
